# v13: Opt+left fails to move in text-like cells

Tags: front-end, keyboard, version-13

I just updated Mathematica to v13 for Intel Mac and encountered a possible bug in frontend: for any text-like cell (text, header, etc.), one fails to use <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to navigate between words leftward as being usually done.
One has to place the cursor at the right end of each word to use <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> for navigation; otherwise the cursor simply hangs there.

I'm wondering if this only happens to me or it is a bug introduced in v13.

Can folks here please confirm?
Thanks!

Version info:

```
13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)
```

Comment: Works fine on "13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)". Looks like the issue is Windows specific. What OS/version are you running.

Comment: No, I’m also on Mac but an Intel one.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was Windows because of `Alt`. On a Mac, it is `Option`.

Comment: I observe the same behavior as the OP on my Intel Mac.  Option-rightarrow works, though.

Comment: On Windows 10. ALT Arrow doesn't work to skip to next words for MM12.3.1 and MM13. CRTL arrow does work for both versions. Are you sure it's ALT Arrow? In guide/SelectingAndTypingInNotebooks only CTRL arrow is mentioned. Alt arrow is  mentioned to navigate through the documentation tabs

Comment: @lou Sorry about the mistake: I meant "Opt" on Mac (rather than "Alt"). Just realised this and have corrected that in the post. Thanks!

Comment: It works normally on my Intel MBP w MMA 13.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I reported this to WRI in CASE:4888262 and the WRI staff were very helpful in helping me out of this issue.

It turned out some of my local settings inherited from previous version were causing the issue so I [reset Mathematica](https://support.wolfram.com/12464) by renaming the `$UserBaseDirectory` to something else and then the issue was gone.

I'll update more with the exact cause while adding my previous settings back piece by piece.